# How to access user's documents?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios7

OK, I admit I'm a newbie to iOS programming (I've mostly played with OSX programming in the past 4 years), so I need your help.

As far as I know, each app has its own "folder" for file storage. (e.g. if you want to add files to VLC, you just open iTunes, go to Apps, select VLC and drag and drop your files in there).

**So, the question(s) is :**

- Is there anything I have to do in order to enable this feature?
- How is this folder accessible? (which path?)
- Am I able to pre-load documents in there?
- Is it possible that I pre-load documents in a folder tree and not just plain files? (as far as I know, as a user, you can't drag'n'drop folder, but only files)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you are asking for File-Sharing Support.
Actually you need add the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key to your app’s `Info.plist` file, and set the value of the key to `YES`. As result user will have possibility to preload files by iTunes.

All files will be available in app `/Documents` directory.  Get path to this directory in such manner:
`NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];`

You can preload only files, there are no possibility to set folder.

More info about this feature you can find in [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH10-SW30).